# How do I compare and unset an object in an array against the other objects in the array?

Tags: php, arrays

**What I'm trying to do:** Compare an array value which is an object with other objects in the array.  If certain object properties in the needle (the object I'm comparing against the other objects) match the same properties in another object in the haystack, then merge certain properties from the needle to the matched object in the haystack and unset the needle.

**Some pseudo-code:**

```
<?php
$haystack = array($obj1, $obj2, $obj3);
if(!empty($haystack)){
    for($x=0;$x<count($haystack);$x++){
        if($haystack[$x]->prop1 == $haystack[$x+1]->prop1 && $haystack[$x]->prop2 == $haystack[$x+1]->prop2){
            $haystack[$x]->combined1 = $haystack[$x]->prop1.','.$haystack[$x+1]->prop1;
            unset($haystack[$x+1]);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you implement a `toArray` method in the objects? If not, `(array) $obj` to cast them to an array, and then use `array_intersect` to determine the difference, if any

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Doing the comparison is relatively easy.  I think the problem has to do with unsetting the next element in the array currently being iterated over.  By accessing $array[$x+1] its moving the iterator forward and messing up the comparison (I think).

Comment: Change `unset($haystack[$x+1])` to `unset($haystack[++$x])`, this increments `$i`, skipping the unset index on the next loop iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding a tad on my comment:

You'll have to change `unset($haystack[$x+1]);` to `unset($haystack[++$x]);`
If, say indexes 0 and 1 are equal, your current loop unsets `$haystack[1]`, keeping the value of `$i` at 0, the loop then continues to increment `$i` with 1 (to 1 in this case), and executes the comparison with `$haystack[1]`, which has just been unset.
Actually incrementing `$i` means that, at the end of the loop `$i` will be 1, instead of 0. That will be incremented once more, and the next time around, the loop will compare indexes 2 and 3.

```
for ($x = 0, $max = count($haystack);$x <$max;++$x)
{
    if ($haystack[$x] == $haystack[$x+1])
    {//only increment if you unset!
        unset($haystack[++$x]);
    }
}
```

That should do the trick. If you want to compare all elements in the given array, then you'll have to nest two loops:

```
for ($x = 0, $max = count($haystack);$x <$max;++$x, $max =count($haystack))
{//re-assign $max after inner loop completes, and reset keys
    for ($j = $x+1;$j<$max;++$j)
    {
        if ($haystack[$x] == $haystack[$j])
        {//No need to increment again
            unset($haystack[$j]);
        }
    }
    $haystack = array_values($haystack);//this resets the keys
}
```

That should solve your problem

Comment: This is much closer than I have been previously. There seems to still be one bug though. If I have a $haystack of 4 objects, 3 of which having the same prop1 and prop2, I'm still winding up with an array of 3 objects instead of two.

Comment: You'll have to use a nested loop for that, then... if you want to compare all elements of the array... I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
        for($x=0;$x<count($haystack);$x++){
            for($y=0;$y<=count($haystack);$y++){
                if($haystack[$x]->prop1 == $haystack[$y]->prop1 && $haystack[$x]->prop2 == $haystack[$y]->prop2){
                    if($haystack[$x]->prop3 == $haystack[$y]->prop3){
                        continue;
                    }else{
                        $haystack[$x]->prop1 .= $haystack[$y]->prop1;
                        unset($haystack[$y]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In retrospect, this was a fairly easy problem to solve.  The issue was trying to mentally keep the iterators straight and knowing how many were needed.  In order for this to work without copying the array or using an intermediary, you just need to instantiate two iterators to iterate over the array simultaneously so you can compare **$array[0-n]** to **$array[0-n]** instead of comparing **$array[0-n]** to **$arrayCopy[0-n]**.